# how to take the gradient of this function?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The book I'm reading has contains these 2 lines of logic and I'm missing an understanding of the underlying theory:

$$ \nabla_{\mathbf{c}} ( -2 \mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{Dc} + \mathbf{c}^T\mathbf{c} ) = 0 $$
is the equal to

$$ -2 \mathbf{D}^T \mathbf{x} + 2\mathbf{c} = 0 $$

Where does the second equation come from?

Comment: What do the variables mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{c}$ column vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and $\mathbf{D}$ a constant $n\times n$ matrix, the equation can be written
$$
  \frac{\partial}{\partial c_i}\left(-2\sum_{j,k=1}^nx_jD_{jk}c_k+\sum_{k=1}^nc_kc_k\right)=0
$$
and evaluating the derivative gives
$$
  -2\sum_{j=1}^nx_jD_{ji}+2c_i=0
$$
that, in vector form, can be expressed as $-2\mathbf{D}^T\mathbf{x}+2\mathbf{c}=0$